# What is faster for RestAPI development .NET or MEAN Stack

Tags: .net, rest, mean

I have an idea on the answer but would love feedback. I have a webapp that is stable but want to expand to a iOS and Android App. What is faster for the webapp backend to create a REST API .NET or MEAN?